# How to Add a shapefile data to postgis(postgres) using c#

Tags: gis, postgis, shapefile, geoserver, arcgis-server

am trying to add **shapefile data to postgis using c#**

```
        string path = browse_path.Text;

        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("CMD.exe");

        Process p = new Process();

        startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

        p = Process.Start(startInfo);

        string chgdir = @"chdir " + @"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin\";

        p.StandardInput.WriteLine(chgdir);

        string pass = @"set PGPASSWORD=postgres";

        p.StandardInput.WriteLine(pass);

        string cmd = @"shp2pgsql -I -s 4326 " + path + " public.states | psql -U postgres -d postgres";

        p.StandardInput.WriteLine(cmd);

        p.WaitForExit();

        p.Close();`
```

and for waiting almost 7-8 mins its not working. my shp file is 160 kb only.. but **the command is working fine if i run it in the cmd** rather then using code..

Comment: Hey there! Is there an error message of some sort? Or the script just freezes? It's huge speculation, but in many cases a database behaves like this when there is something or someone else blocking the target table/database with another process.

Comment: Why are you setting UseShellExecute = false? Try to set it to true, so that shp2pgsql uses os shell.

Answer (score 1):

This is a function I wrote to import shapefiles to PG. It uses Nuget packages CliWrap and Npgsql and I just copied shp2pgsql and its dependencies to a project folder 'Tools' so it can be run on a machine that doesn't have PostgreSQL installed. Its a bit messy and you might need to add error handling but it worked for my needs.

```
    public async static Task<bool> OutputSHPtoPSGLAsync(string shpfile, string host, string user, string pwd, string db, string schema = "public", bool dropIfExists = true, string table = "[SHPNAME]")
    {
        FileInfo shp = new FileInfo(shpfile);
        if (!shp.Exists) return false;
        if (table == "[SHPNAME]") table = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(shpfile).ToLower();

        string args = string.Format("{0} {1}.{2}", shpfile, schema, table);
        Command cli = Cli.Wrap(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"tools\shp2pgsql.exe")).WithArguments(args);
        ExecutionResult eo = await cli.ExecuteAsync();

        string sql = eo.StandardOutput;
        if (dropIfExists) sql = sql.Replace("CREATE TABLE", string.Format("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS \"{0}\".\"{1}\";\r\nCREATE TABLE", schema, table));

        string constring = string.Format("Host={0};Username={1};Password={2};Database={3}", host, user, pwd, db);
        using (NpgsqlConnection connection = new NpgsqlConnection(constring))
        {
            connection.Open();
            new NpgsqlCommand(sql, connection).ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I was looking at NetTopologySuite which has type definitions compatible with Npgsql and PostGIS but its all still pre-release and couldn't be bothered working it out.